# Why can't I install this android program over wireless ADB?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb, android-5.0-lollipop

https://github.com/JonWoodlief/android-pololu-maestro-ssc

I'm intending to use this to learn how to manipulate a maestro-ssc card hooked up to my android via micro-usb to mini-usb cable. I'm running a verizon Galaxy S5 (SM-G900V) and I'm rooted on android 5.0. I'm running Wireless ADB using Konnect-ADB, and the debug information is displayed on my Android Monitor in android studio, and it's listed as a device when I run adb devices.

I build the apk using gradle, and run

```
adb -d install C:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\android-pololu-maestro-
ssc-master\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
```

to install. But it gives me

```
error: no devices found
adb: error: connect failed: no devices found
- waiting for device -
```

And it does nothing more than this

While it's waiting I can run adb devices in a command prompt and it shows that the device is connected.

Comment: drop the `-d`. it means *USB Device*

Comment: Thanks Alex that was the first problem. Still giving an error but I got a little farther at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex P. Submitted it as a comment but I figured I should answer to close the question.

That -d flag I was using was limiting the install command to look for a USB device. This was a wireless device so that didn't work. Since this is the only ADB device I had connected dropping the -d worked fine, but if I had multiple devices I would have to use a -s flag along with the serial to choose the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

have you used the `adb connect <host>:<port>` as shown on ADB Konnect?

Have you been into the phone's developer option and enable **DEBUGGING** as well as enabling **ALLOW DEBUG OVER TCP/NETWORK**?